# I want to prove $ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx = \infty $

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I prove this integral diverges?

$$ \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx = \infty $$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}=  \int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}+\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \\
> \int_{0}^{1}\frac{e^{-x}}{x} \\
> e^{-1}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x} 
$$
which diverges.

Answer (score 4):

For $0\lt x\lt 1$, our function is $\gt e^{-1}\frac{1}{x}$.

Thus $\int_\epsilon^1 \frac{e^{-x}}{x}\,dx \gt -e^{-1}\log(\epsilon)$. But $-\log(\epsilon)$ blows up as $\epsilon$ approaches $0$ from the right.

Answer (score 1):

$s>0$

$$ \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} dx = \frac{1}{s} $$

$$ \int _1^\infty \int_0^\infty e^{-sx} dx ds = \int _1^\infty \frac{1}{s}ds $$

$$ \int_0^\infty  \int _1^\infty e^{-sx}  ds dx = \int _1^\infty \frac{1}{s}ds $$

$$ \int_0^\infty   (\frac{e^{-sx}}{-x}) |_{s=1}^\infty   dx = \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{s}ds $$

$$ \int_0^\infty  \frac{e^{-x}}{x} dx  = \ln\infty -\ln 1 =  \infty$$